# MYSQL - Find the largest historical result?

Tags: mysql, caching, mariadb

I am running a mysql server. I am trying to tune my cache mechanism. I am viewing my cache statistics below and I am concerned about the number of lowmem prunes as well as the not cached stat. I believe I have enough memory dedicated but I feel it is possible that my maximum query size may be too small.

```
mysql> SHOW STATUS LIKE "qcache%"
    -> ;
+-------------------------+----------+
| Variable_name           | Value    |
+-------------------------+----------+
| Qcache_free_blocks      | 297      |
| Qcache_free_memory      | 15375480 |
| Qcache_hits             | 24724191 |
| Qcache_inserts          | 23954609 |
| Qcache_lowmem_prunes    | 2011492  |
| Qcache_not_cached       | 6987151  |
| Qcache_queries_in_cache | 6004     |
| Qcache_total_blocks     | 12386    |
+-------------------------+----------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Is there a way to get the server to report back a historical statistic for the largest query ever returned? My intention is to discover how large the returned query data is in order to better tune the cache. I feel that the not cached number may be too large and that stems from not having a large enough maximum query.

Comment: Those values are useless without `Uptime` and `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'query%'.

Comment: There is no history.

Comment: `query_cache_size` should not be more than 50M -- because of the cost of pruning.